# Externally Requesting Browser Test Created URL for Relaxed Replication

Tags: 8, routes, testing

I am trying to write a browser test for for a workspace replication via relaxed web services using the multiversion, replication and relaxed modules. For this purpose I set up an external Drupal installation as a content repository to clone from.

The content repository is installed locally and is reachable as I have tested it with an other Drupal instance as a replication target.

My problem is that the Drupal instance created by the browser test always gives me a 404 error once I try to reach it like follows:

```
\Doctrine\CouchDB\CouchDBClient::create([
      'url' => 'http://replication_user:password@browsertest.url/relaxed/live',
      'port' => 80,
 ])->getDatabaseInfo('live');
```

The local url and WorkspacePointers are set up correctly and the rest resources are also active. I even have a custom Drupal profile which activates all needed services and writes all configs for this functionality to work and it is being used by dozens of sites, but using relaxed replication in a test (even with the working profile) seems impossible…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. To target the current test instance in a request one needs to set the http  client user agent header to `drupal_generate_test_ua(drupal_valid_test_ua())`.